# 'too dangerous to let live' or 'too dangerous to be let live'?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases, idioms, expressions

I was writing something down that came to me in a passing while I was watching TV, and I found myself discombobulated with the way one should phrase the notion of letting someone do something in the manner illustrated by the example in the question I posed. I know of a book with the title 'too dangerous to let live', but the sentence I was writing down feel so much intuitive with the second form, that is, having 'be' before the phrase 'let + verb'.

The sentence is,

'Besmirching what I thought to be too pure to be let exist, deflowering what I reckoned to be too beautiful to be let waste'.

Is this sentence grammatically right? Or is this one a better alternative?

'Besmirching what I thought to be too pure to be let to exist, deflowering what I reckoned to be too beautiful to be let to waste'.

The problem here is, I was reminded by that book I mentioned with the title 'Too Dangerous To Let Live' which would then suggest that my sentence is better if phrased this way,

'Besmirching what I thought to be too pure to let exist, deflowering what I reckoned to be too beautiful to let waste'

I also have thought of another alternative which further baffles me,

'Besmirching what I thought to be too pure to be let existed, deflowering what I reckoned to be too beautiful to be let wasted'

So do you have any ideas or insights on which one should be correct? Any answer is very much appreciated!

Comment: You can say something is "too poisonous to use", but you could also say it's "too poisonous to be used" (and [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+poisonous+to+use%2Ctoo+poisonous+to+be+used&year_start=1900&year_end=2007&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows both of them exist), so by analogy I think "to be let waste" and "to let waste" are fine. I don't like "let to waste", though.

Comment: I think I understand it more clearly now Peter. I guess the thing that actually side-tracked me is the unchanged form for past tense and infinitive 'let'. Your examples illustrated that to me. Thanks man.

Comment: This may be a parochial (U.S.) response, but I think that most U.S. English speakers would telescope your original sentence to something like "Besmirching what I thought too pure to exist, deflowering what I reckoned too beautiful to waste." The shortened form undoubtedly alters the underlying meaning if taken literally, but I think most U.S. hearers would understand it as you intend—as describing states of being, four times over.

Answer (score 3):

It's archaic, but the construction *to be let exist* does have a more modern equivalent.

Take the sentence "I let him exist": this can be re-ordered as "Him, I let exist", with the same meaning of "Him, I *allowed to* exist". Note that using *let* means that *to* does not appear, as it must when using *allow*.

Thus *to be let exist* means *to be allowed to exist*. The verb *exist* is infinitive, and *let* does not permit *to*.

*To be let existed* is ungrammatical: *exist* must be infinitive.

*To let exist* is the more modern equivalent, *to allow to exist*.

> Besmirching what I thought to be too pure to be ***allowed to*** exist...

More interesting is *to be let waste. Waste* here is again an infinitive verb, with a variety of possible meanings (per OED)

> **9.** In unfavourable sense: To spend, consume, employ uselessly or without adequate result.
>   **†13.** To lose quality, deteriorate, spoil.

So the second half can be modernised as

> ...deflowering what I reckoned to be too beautiful to be allowed to *go to waste*.
>   ...deflowering what I reckoned to be too beautiful to be allowed to *deterioriate.*

Comment: I agree with everything you say, but I would like some clarification concerning the first sentence of your answer. Have you seen instances of *to be let exist* in use?

Comment: @Irene No, but then I don't tend to read the sort of historical novels where it might appear.

Comment: I find your explanation enlightening. Thank you there Andrew!

Comment: I don't think that "to be let" can be used. Or at least, I've never heard it used, and it sounds very strange to me. "to let exist" makes sense, but when I see "to be let exist" I have no idea what it means.

Comment: @Irene, Try Charles Dickens Great Expectations. "Now lookee here," he said, " the question being whether you're to be let to live". https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=s_gtAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA6&dq=%22be+let+to+live%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwB2oVChMIjff5g7zXyAIVRj8aCh0qCABP#v=onepage&q=%22be%20let%20to%20live%22&f=false

Comment: @chasly from UK: Interesting. Thank you for the reference. This however is different from "to be let exist", where we have two bare infinitives in a row. Your citation sounds less strange to my ears, although I believe that contemporary grammar accepts only "allowed" instead of "let".

Answer (score 0):

The only form of catenation that **let** regularly licenses is complex catenation with base forms of verbs:

> **simple catenation with base form // to-infinitive // ing-form**:
>    **He should let think / die / come // to think // thinking.* (*He should let go* is idiomatic, a multi-word verb. And *Live and let live* is
>   another set expression.)
>
> **complex catenation with to-infinitive:** 
>   **He should let them to think / to come / to sleep.*
>
> **complex catenation with bare infinitive:**
>   He should let them think... / come / sleep.

Even this latter construction (let + DO + base-form) doesn't passivise in general:

**?They should be let think / come / sleep.*

More acceptable is the passivisation of the synonymous 'allow + to-infinitive':

*They should be allowed to think(...) / come / sleep.*

(Ngrams for the alternatives using come, sleep, live, have, marry, die... all show either no results for the *let* version or a huge preference for the *allow to* {ie *be allowed to*} version).

Comment: I am aware of the two forms of complex catenation that you stated above but the simple catenation is actually pretty new to me. I appreciate your answers.

Comment: @Suffian Azizan Complex catenation with ing-forms is also possible with some verbs; the Cobuild treatment of 'verb + ing-forms' gives a more thorough analysis of three different isomorphic structures. See at http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23575&p=82916&hilit=go+shopping+phase#p82916 . The authors of CGEL, in their classification of catenative verbs, list _Class 2: "Catenative verbs [which appear] in both simple and complex construction"_. A good article on simple catenatives may be found at http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs .

Answer (score 0):

> 'too dangerous to let live'
>
> or
>
> 'too dangerous to be let live'?

'too dangerous to let live' [correct]

'too dangerous to be let live' [incorrect]

'too dangerous to be let to live' [correct but archaic]

**Example**

"Now lookee here," he said, " the question being whether you're to be let to live".  [Charles Dickens Great Expectations.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NNcNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA170&dq=%22be%20let%20to%20live%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIjff5g7zXyAIVRj8aCh0qCABP#v=onepage&q=%22be%20let%20to%20live%22&f=false)